# Nested mongo $add and $multiply resulting in can't convert from BSON type NULL to Date error

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

As part of the project stage of an aggregation, I'm trying to add a timezone offset to a date so I can then group by the modified date.

The docs look like:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59ca593a9a94192d4f9d4452"),
  "updatedAt": new Date(1506433338535),
  "createdAt": new Date(1506433338535),
  "pubTimezone": "Europe/London",
  "text": "Buhzado fi apewem tuglikler mo lokwa pu luv aluar aghesgu li kelesipo bi.",
  "pubDate": new Date(1506433338052),
  "pubTimezoneOffsetHours": 0
}
```

Relevant code:

```
[
  { 
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id',       
      text: '$text',
      pubTimezone: '$pubTimezone',
      pubTimezoneOffsetHours: '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours',
      pubDate: {
        $add: [ '$pubDate', {
          $multiply: [ '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours', 60, 60, 1000 ]
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: '$pubDate' },
        month: { $month: '$pubDate' },
        day: { $dayOfMonth: '$pubDate' }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      items: {
        $push: {
          _id: '$_id',
          updatedAt: '$updatedAt',
          createdAt: '$createdAt',
          text: '$text',
          pubTimezone: '$pubTimezone',
          pubTimezoneOffsetHours: '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours',
          pubDate: {
            $subtract: [ '$pubDate', {
              $multiply: [ '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours', 60, 60, 1000 ]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This results in Error: can't convert from BSON type NULL to Date

I have searched through the data for { pubTimezoneOffsetHours: null } and updated all entries that had null values to have an integer value.

When I remove '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours' from the $multiply array, the error disappears.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post 1 or 2 examples of the docs you are flowing through that pipe?

Comment: I've added an example doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your $project/$push example because that's a syntax error but focusing on your goal, you probably have a null somewhere in `pubTimezoneOffsetHours` (still) and that's making the adjusted date null because a null in the `$multiply` array will force the whole thing to null.  Try this on for size:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {adjDate: {$add: [
    "$pubDate",
    {$multiply: [ {$ifNull: ['$pubTimezoneOffsetHours',0]}, 60, 60, 1000 ]} 
    ] } 
}}
                ]);
```

You can then `{$group: {_id:"$adjDate"}}`any way you like.

Comment: Yeah the $push was there because I copy and pasted it from the group stage by mistake. I've updated the example with the group and project stage so there is more context.

Comment: I replaced '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours' with {$ifNull: ['$pubTimezoneOffsetHours',0]} in the multiply array. The error has gone, which is great. Does the $ifNull bit still return '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours' when it's not null, or do I need to have '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours' in the array as well?

Comment: @user3381520  "Yes."  If $pubTimezoneOffsetHours is NOT null, then $ifNull returns its value.   Don't put it in the array.   And don't be shy about hitting the up arrow.

Comment: Right I see now, $ifNull returns '$pubTimezoneOffsetHours' unless it's null, in which case it returns 0. Pretty cool. Thanks @buzz-moschetti, you've answered my question, much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future and wanting to do timezone date operators stuff at query time [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310) might be ready.